# Nest Module `forRootAsync` is invoked before `forFeatureAsync`

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest-dynamic-modules

I'm trying to create a custom NestJS module. I'm providing 4 different methods `forRoot`, `forRootAsync`, `forFeature`, `forFeatureAsync`, although I'm using only two of it `forRootAsync` and `forFeatureAsync`.

I've imported module in `AppModule` and configured using `forRootAsync`, then also imported same module in a feature module `UploadModule` and configured using `forFeatureAsync`.

The problem is that undesirably `forFeatureAsync` is being invoked before `forRootAsync`. Mean my module is first initialized in `UploadModule` and then in `AppModule`, although purposefully it should do exactly opposite of it.

Please pay an attention to the source code of `FileStorageService`. This service should desirably first configure the `baseDir` - base directory of every upload. Then in feature, or even for the app module it should create every directory provided in the options.

## Custom Module Source Code

`file-storage.module.ts`

```
import { DynamicModule, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { FileStorageService } from './file-storage.service';
import {
  ASYNC_OPTIONS_TYPE,
  MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
  OPTIONS_TYPE,
} from './file-storage.module-defination';

@Module({
  providers: [],
  exports: [],
})
export class FileStorageModule {
  static forRoot(options: typeof OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
    // omit for better clarity
  }

  static forRootAsync(options: typeof ASYNC_OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: FileStorageModule,
      imports: options.imports,

      providers: [
        {
          provide: MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
          useClass: options.useClass,
          useFactory: options.useFactory,
          inject: options.inject,
        },

        FileStorageService,
      ],

      exports: [FileStorageService],
    };
  }

  static forFeature(options: typeof OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
    // omit for better clarity
  }

  static forFeatureAsync(options: typeof ASYNC_OPTIONS_TYPE): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: FileStorageModule,
      imports: options.imports,

      providers: [
        {
          provide: MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
          useClass: options.useClass,
          useFactory: options.useFactory,
          inject: options.inject,
        },

        FileStorageService,
      ],

      exports: [FileStorageService],
    };
  }
}
```

`file-storage.service.ts`

```
import { Inject, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  FileStorageModuleOptions,
  MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN,
} from './file-storage.module-defination';
import * as path from 'path';
import { mkdirSync, statSync } from 'fs';

@Injectable()
export class FileStorageService {
  private readonly logger = new Logger(FileStorageService.name);
  private static baseDir = '';
  directories = new Map<string, string>();

  constructor(
    @Inject(MODULE_OPTIONS_TOKEN) private options: FileStorageModuleOptions,
  ) {
    this.logger.log(options);

    if (options.baseDirectory) {
      this.logger.log(`Base Directory: ${options.baseDirectory}`);
      FileStorageService.baseDir = options.baseDirectory;
      syncDirectory(this.baseDirectory);
    }

    if (!options.directories?.length) return;

    for (const dir of options.directories) {
      try {
        let directory = this.baseDirectory;

        if (typeof dir.path == 'string') {
          directory = path.join(directory, dir.path);
        } else {
          for (const p of dir.path) {
            directory = path.join(directory, p);
          }
        }

        syncDirectory(directory);
        this.directories.set(dir.name, directory);
        this.logger.log(
          `Synced Directory: ${dir.name} | ${dir.path} | ${directory}`,
        );
      } catch {
        this.logger.warn(`Error Syncing Directory: ${dir.name} | ${dir.path}`);
      }
    }
  }
}


function syncDirectory(dir: string) {
  try {
    mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true });
  } catch (err) {
    // omit for better clarity
  }
}
```

## AppModule and UploadModule Source Code

`app.module.ts`

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { SequelizeModule } from '@nestjs/sequelize';
import { AuthModule } from './auth/auth.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { TodoModule } from './todo/todo.module';
import { User } from './shared/user.model';
import { Todo } from './todo/todo.model';
import { UploadModule } from './upload/upload.module';
import { FileStorageModule } from './file-storage/file-storage.module';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ..., // N modules imported

    FileStorageModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],

      useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => {
        return {
          baseDirectory: config.get('STORAGE_DIR'),
        };
      },

      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),

    ..., // N modules imported

    UploadModule, // It is definitely last in Queue
  ],

  controllers: [],
  providers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

`upload.module.ts`

```
import { BadRequestException, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MulterModule } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { UploadService } from './upload.service';
import { UploadController } from './upload.controller';
import { storageDirectories } from 'src/config';
import * as multer from 'multer';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import * as mime from 'mime-types';
import { FileStorageModule } from 'src/file-storage/file-storage.module';
import { UploadDirectories } from './upload.interface';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ..., // N modules imported

    FileStorageModule.forFeatureAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        directories: [
          {
            name: UploadDirectories.ProfilePicture,
            path: UploadDirectories.ProfilePicture,
          },
        ],
      }),
    }),
  ],

  providers: [...],
  controllers: [...],
})
export class UploadModule {}
```

## Logs of the application

Most of the logs are stripped, we're interested in the order of exection of-course.

```
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [NestFactory] Starting Nest application...
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] AppModule dependencies initialized +39ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] SequelizeModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] PassportModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] MulterModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [FileStorageService] Object:
{
  "directories": [
    {
      "name": "user/profile-picture",
      "path": "user/profile-picture"
    }
  ]
}

[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [FileStorageService] Synced Directory: user/profile-picture | user/profile-picture | user/profile-pict
ure
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigHostModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] FileStorageModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] ConfigModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] UploadModule dependencies initialized +1ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [FileStorageService] Object:
{
  "baseDirectory": "/var/cool-todo"
}
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [FileStorageService] Base Directory: /var/cool-todo
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] FileStorageModule dependencies initialized +2ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader] JwtModule dependencies initialized +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [InstanceLoader]
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [RoutesResolver] UploadController {/api/v1/upload}: +0ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [RouterExplorer] Mapped {/api/v1/upload, POST} route +1ms
[Nest] 355  - 12/08/2023, 3:25:56 PM     LOG [NestApplication] Nest application successfully started +5ms
```

I've tried:

- Arrange module imports in `AppModule`, placed UploadModule after `FileStorageModule`. Definitely I suspect that `Async` has something to do with it, so no way out.
- Googling, not found anywhere mentioned.

I expect:

- If issue is due to `Async`, explain the behavior, so I would never see myself cornered again.
- Definitely the solution, I need to get out of it.
- I cannot sacrifice async, as I need `ConfigService` dependency, I want to set the storage directory from environment.